# How to delete an object in a list in Parse by using ItemLongClick?

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I am trying to make it so ItemLongClick on a comment in the comment list deletes the user's comment but its not working:

```
private ParseQueryAdapter<Comment> mainCommentAdapter;
private CommentAdapter favoriteCommentAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.post_thread_layout);

mainCommentAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Comment>(this, Comment.class);
mainCommentAdapter.setTextKey("commentText");

favoriteCommentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this);

final ListView commentsListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    commentsListView.setAdapter(mainCommentAdapter);
    commentsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            final Comment comment = mainCommentAdapter.getItem(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), commentsListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PostThreadActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("DELETE COMMENT");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Delete the meal
                    comment.deleteInBackground();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do nothing
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

According to Parse.com documentation to delete an object simply:

```
myObject.deleteInBackground();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is my Comment.java

```
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

@ParseClassName("Comment")
public class Comment extends ParseObject {
    public Comment() {
        // A default constructor is required.
    }

    public ParseUser getUser() {
        return getParseUser("user");
    }

    public void setUser(ParseUser value) {
        put("user", value);
    }

    public String getCommentText() {
        return getString("commentText");
    }

    public void setCommentText(String commentText) {
        put("commentText", commentText);
    }

    // Associate each comment with a post (meal)
    public void setMeal(Meal meal) {
        put("meal", meal);
    }

    // Get the post for this item
    public Meal getMeal()  {
        return (Meal) getParseObject("meal");
    }

}
```

CommentAdapter.java

```
public class CommentAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Comment> {

public CommentAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Comment>() {
        public ParseQuery<Comment> create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Comment");
            query.include("user");
            //query.include("owner"); //<-- from CodePath tutorial delete if not needed
            query.addAscendingOrder("createdAt"); //add setTime(like anywall) to the comments
            return query;
        }

    });

}

@Override
public View getItemView(Comment comment, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.comment_item, null);
    }

    //show the submitted words in Comments adapter
    TextView commentTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment_view);  //Get the textView for the title from item_list_favorites.xml and convert it to a variable titleTextView. Then gets the submitted Event title info from getters and setters: getTitle, then set it as text of TitleTextView //simple.
    commentTextView.setText(comment.getCommentText());

    //show username for each comment
    TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username_view);  //Get the textView for the title from item_list_favorites.xml and convert it to a variable titleTextView. Then gets the submitted Event title info from getters and setters: getTitle, then set it as text of TitleTextView //simple.
    usernameTextView.setText(comment.getUser().getUsername());

    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: how much more should I post? Because the entire activity is pretty long. (edit: I changed/added some more codes) Now the errors are gone, but the object still won't delete even after I click on the item and click YES on the Dialog.

Comment: Have you checked that the item isn't deleted from the Parse back end, and may still just be showing locally? Are there any errors in logcat? deleteInBackground() is async, so how long have you waited after executing the code?

Comment: I just checked Parse.com, the item is still there. I have waited a few mintes after the comment section is loaded. its still not deleting. I don't see any errors in logcat

Answer (score 0):

try  with callback

```
comment.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Delete Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: okay, so I did that and this is the log for the error:

`10-12 01:39:34.034  15243-15243/com.parse.mealspotting E/Delete` `Error﹕ object not found for delete`

`10-12 01:39:34.199  15243-15243/com.parse.mealspotting E/Delete` `Error﹕ object not found for delete`

Comment: cross check you `comment` objectId wich you want to delete Is it exist or not at `parse.com`.

Comment: let me check, I'm pretty sure it exists

Comment: yeah it exists on parse.com

Comment: ok, I edited the question and included the entire Comment.java and CommentAdapter.java

Comment: you are doing something wrong here `mainCommentAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Comment>(this, Comment.class);
favoriteCommentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this);` you have use two adapter. default and your custom

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make the mainCommentAdapter adapt the list items with both username info and comment info, so I did a workaround to create another list adapter(favoriteCommentAdapter) and then make it so that when people go to the list: it adapts immediately from mainCommentAdapter to favoriteCommentAdapter.

Comment: Still stuck, any help?